# Recover encrypted container files from corrupted drive

Tags: data-recovery

I have got 2 container files(~400GB, ~100GB)(encrypted veracrypt containers) on my hard drive mixed with oder regular files on an ntfs partition. Today my drive wasn't recognized any more and it said there is damage. I couldn't work it out. Then I tried "ease us partition master"(program) and it somehow get back my partition. The regular files work. I tried to mount both my containers but it didn't work. Then I tried to recover header and at that point I realised that in my explorer both container files are listet as 0kb file size(NOT over 500GB). What can I do? I guess the program did mix up something how can I recover my container files?Or better: the previous versions of the container files(~400GB, and ~100GB)? Any possibility? These files in the containers are important. I hope there is any chance to recover. TIA

update:
ok I gave up on those containers. in these containers were files of an old win 7 pc. before I formatet the win 7 pc to a fresh linux machine I saved the files in these containers. I did now a ddrescue copy (IMG file) of the hard drive sda in linux. on this fresh linux install were not that much files and most of the hard drive is empty. maybe I can recover from this ddrescue IMG file?

Comment: If they're *very* important, you might try commercial data recovery, at considerable expense. *Do not* attempt more DIY recovery... the best programs have a fairly low success rate. Best bet is to restore from your last disk image.

Answer (score 0):

**Your failures until now**

1. You do not a have backup.
2. You did not bother to create a container header backup.
3. You played with a suspicous drive instead of duplicating it to prevent being exposed to possible drive degeneration.

**Outlook**

1. The recovery process now depends on the question if your container headers are affected. If yes, your data is lost. A professional recovery company would need to read a defective sector correctly what I doubt.
2. If the information about the clusters belonging to the containers has been destroyed (FAT or MFT dammage when running a Microsoft operating system) recovery is only possible if the clusters of the files are laid out sequently. This is most probably only the case when the containers had been the first file that you wrote to the disk.

As to what Pippik wrote "the best programs have a fairly low success rate." this statement is way too generalized and not really specific due to the lack of numbers. It really depends on the kind of dammage.

Update 30.6.2020 9:37 ECT

Regarding your broken harddrive with containers having a file size of 0 there might be still the information about the starting clusters of your containers.
Assumining a defragmentation free drive you could save the content of the drive starting with this cluster to generate two new files with a length of at least 100GB and 400GB.
As the data of this artifical files does not start directly at position zero it has to be stripped by the administrative header that starts with the fingerprint "FILE" (see third party NTFS documentation).

Regarding your intended search on your linux machine you would need a file-oriented alternative to the testcrypt program which only finds lost partitions.

Comment: I have the header backups on serveral other drives backed up but because it shows 0kb file size of containers I can't do anything in veracrypt.